# Postgresql date type has a void of one century at 0 AD

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm working with PostgreSQL and while working with dates around the moment of birth of Christ suddenly encountered a problem with 0 AD point in time.

Say,

```
update mytable 
   set mydate='0000-09-01' 
where id=1;
```

gives me

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "0000-09-01"`

while both

```
update mytable 
  set mydate='0001-09-01' 
where id=1;
```

and

```
update mytable 
   set mydate='0001-09-01 BC' 
where id=1;
```

work fine.

I.e. the problem is that I cannot have 0 AD dates being stored in my database, which makes a one-century void in my timeline. Has anyone encountered the same problem? Is this a bug which is going to be fixed in the next PostgreSQL release? Is there any workaround (except of storing dates as strings) out there?

Comment: Well, there never was a year 0000: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero  `date '0001-12-31 BC' + interval '1 day'` yields `0001-01-01`

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was so sure that there must be 0 AD year so that I didn't even investigate the theoretical part. Thanks again!